# About Invoking ChildForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form. I want to make sure that the RegisterForm.cs form comes as childform when the toggle button I added on this form is activated. It works in a different position from the main panel when I call it normally. Whatever I've done, I haven't been able to solve this problem, can you help me with that?

FormMainMenu.cs

```
public void OpenChildForm(Form childForm)
{
    if (currentChildForm != null)
    {
        //open only form
        currentChildForm.Close();
    }
    currentChildForm = childForm;
    childForm.TopLevel = false;
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panelDesktop.Controls.Add(childForm);
    panelDesktop.Tag = childForm;
    childForm.BringToFront();
    childForm.Show();
    lblTitleChildForm.Text = childForm.Text;
}
```

SozlesmeFormu.cs

```
public partial class SozlesmeFormu : Form
{
    private bool toggleCheck = false;

    public SozlesmeFormu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Multiline = true;
        textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
    }


    private void toggleSozlesme_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toggleCheck = true;
        toggleSozlesme.Enabled = false;
        toggleSozlesme.OnBackColor = Color.DarkGray;
        this.Close();

        FormMainMenu formMain = new FormMainMenu();
        formMain.OpenChildForm(new RegisterForm());

    }
}
```

Whatever I did, I couldn't call RegisterForm as childform. It's always irrelevant from the main panel.

Comment: This line, `FormMainMenu formMain = new FormMainMenu();`, is creating an invisible instance (you never show it) which is why it never shows up.  You need a reference to the ACTUAL instance of `formMain` that is already showing on your screen.  Is `SozlesmeFormu` also a child form of `formMain`?

Comment: Yes, child form. I don't know very well, so I can't find a solution. I know a little python programming, but the c# language was a little harsh on me, :) 
How exactly can I solve this problem? I can throw out the whole code if you want.

Comment: If `SozlesmeFormu` is already a child of the `formMain`, then you can use [TopLevelControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.toplevelcontrol?view=net-5.0) to get a reference to the main form.  Try changing `FormMainMenu formMain = new FormMainMenu();` to `FormMainMenu formMain = (FormMainMenu)this.TopLevelControl;`.

Comment: "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"